# Print/Generate PDF of embedded power bi report

Tags: javascript, powerbi

I have embedded a power bi report into my website. I want to implement save to pdf or print feature in it. Is there any way to implement these features?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to use the Power BI API to embed your report and then use javascript to launch the print dialog. `window.print();`

Out of the box there is no button inside Power BI that export your report as a PDF as is.

On the Power BI Service, you have the possibility to export your report in PowerPoint, but the exported data are single static jpg of your report, e.g. no interaction is possible.

Here on GitHub you can find how to interact with PowerBI via javascript
[Embedding Basics](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embedding-Basics#print-a-report)

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have used `report.print()` of powerbi.js for printing the report.

Comment: report.print() does not work for me? You got any idea? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55052150/how-to-generate-pdf-output-of-powerbi-embedded-report   @Sonali