# Export/Download powerbi embedded report in PDF/CSV

Tags: reactjs, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, export-to-pdf, powerbi-rest-api

I want to export the reports and save them as PDF/CSV file on click of a custom button on my react application.

This is the screenshot of my embedded report in my react application:
[image]

I am using powerbi-client-react and following their documentation, but haven't found any way to export data using a custom button.

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please don't post your code as images.

Answer (score 0):

Could the users simply print from the page and choose to print as a pdf?
[image]

Comment: No. That is not an option. We need to download them on the button click.

Comment: check this post. it looks like they implemented an html button.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55052150/how-to-generate-pdf-output-of-powerbi-embedded-report